# How to let php artisan serve run as a background server to work like Apache?

Tags: php

I setup a Laravel app on a VPS. It's for demonstration purposes only.

I would ssh login to the VPS using PuTTY and type:

```
php artisan serve --host x.x.x.x
```

Everything works fine. However, when I close the PuTTY connection, the server shuts down.

Is it possible to let the artisan server run in the background just like Apache?

Answer (score 17):

You can [run any shell command in the background by adding `&` to the end](https://askubuntu.com/a/88092/453746). If you want it to continue to run after you've disconnected, then run it with `nohup`

```
nohup php artisan serve &
```

To kill it later, you'll be given a process ID, but don't be fooled because this kicks off other processes that will persist even when killed. To get the actual server PID, you can find it by filtering `ps` output with `grep`

```
ps -ef | grep "$PWD/server.php"
```

Should give you some output like this:

> jeff   23978 23977  0 16:50 pts/4    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php7.0 -S 127.0.0.1:8000 /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
>
> jeff   24059 18581  0 16:51 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /path/to/laravel-project/server.php

The first number after your username is the PID you want to kill.

```
kill 23978
```

Don't do this for a production site, but a quick demo might be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the quickest way to do this, at least on a temporary level, is to use screen - You can run it in a screen session and then Ctrl-a then d in Putty/shell to minimize it.  It will continue running after your session closes.

You can resume and kill or restart later.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Jeff's answer, you might want to doublecheck if the command stopped.
In my case something like this happened:

##### create

```
nohup php artisan serve &
ps -ef | grep "$PWD/server.php"
```

output example:

> jeff 23978 23977 0 16:50 pts/4 00:00:00 /usr/bin/php7.0 -S 127.0.0.1:8000 /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
>
> jeff 24059 18581 0 16:51 pts/4 00:00:00 grep --color=auto /path/to/laravel-project/server.php

##### kill and double check

```
kill 23978
ps -ef | grep "$PWD/server.php"
```

output example:

> jeff 23964 23977 0 16:50 pts/4 00:00:00 /usr/bin/php7.0 -S 127.0.0.1:8001 /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
>
> jeff 24059 18581 0 16:51 pts/4 00:00:00 grep --color=auto /path/to/laravel-project/server.php

##### issue

The `php artisan serve` had not actually stopped but just changed ports and ID!

```
id: 23978 => 23964 port: 127.0.0.1:8000 => 127.0.0.1:8001
```

##### solution

run the `kill` comment with the ID to the right side first, which you can also get with this command:

```
ps aux | grep artisan
```

so in order it would be:

```
kill 23977
ps -ef | grep "$PWD/server.php"
```

output example:

> jeff 23964     1 0 16:50 pts/4 00:00:00 /usr/bin/php7.0 -S 127.0.0.1:8001 /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
>
> jeff 24059 18581 0 16:51 pts/4 00:00:00 grep --color=auto /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
> If the number changes to 1 it died. Then:

```
kill 23964
ps -ef | grep "$PWD/server.php"
```

output example:

> jeff 24059 18581 0 16:51 pts/4 00:00:00 grep --color=auto /path/to/laravel-project/server.php
> And the `php artisan serve` should stop.