# How to run laravel server as a service which continously run

Tags: laravel

I am using web socket for communication . At Local i just run the php artisan serve but on live server how can i make a service which run this continously.

I have no idea how to do it. please any body guide me about this. Give me example of code

Comment: On which server are you deploying your application?

Comment: I m using linux server

Comment: Simple and not recommended solution is to run this command: `nohup php artisan serve &`. For more info check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25438177/12756335

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: You might look at one of the open source packages that already implements such a thing; for example, https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction. Even if you don't use them, they'll provide a useful example of how it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is not the way to setup your production env. php artisan serve creates a local development env. It should only be used for development and local testing. [Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> Warning
>
> This web server is designed to aid application development. It may
> also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations
> that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a
> full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

For your production env you should use a webserver like ngix, apache or litespeed.
Laravel docs for webserver configuration ([link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#web-server-configuration))